# add --> as delimiter to the URL pattern

Tags: php, regex, string, url

For extracting URL I use this regex:

```
'/https?\:\/\/[^\",\s\]\|]+/i'
```

(finishes with space, ", comma or |).

**The problem is I also need to add "`-->`"** (3 symbols `-->`) as a break of the URL. However no luck.

P.S. I know this is not a perfect URL validation however URLs are stored within the string in the db and space, comma, ", | and --> are definitely the delimiters of the URL (if met at the end).

Comment: My suggestion is adding one more pattern that includes everything such as `pattern -->(.*?)` and at preg_match function, you can select the first one but second one, so that this will work, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following *regex* should do it :

```
https?:\/\/.*?(?=\s|,|"|\||-->|$)
```

see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aXVaZy/3)

Comment: Sorry, but http://www.example.com/img/ri/3742-17 test is not passed as it cuts where the dash is. Sorry.

Comment: @Haradzieniec check updated answer. now it should work :)

Answer (score 1):

To stop at a multi-character delimiter, the pattern is to repeatedly advance by 1 character until you find the delimiter in a lookahead:

```
(?:(?!delimiter).)*
```

In your case:

```
https?://(?:(?!-->)[^",\]\s|])+
```